# Puedo editar la cabecera y pie de pagina de un ShowRibbonPrintPreview?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Estoy enviando a imprimir un `GridView` con el método `.ShowRibbonPrintPreview`, puedo hacer que la información de la cabecera y pie de pagina sea asignada por medio de código, Ejemplo.

```
string nomEmpresa = "Este es el nombre de la empresa";
```

Luego no sé asignar esta variable a lo que sería el título del `ShowRibbonPrintPreview`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
        GridViewComprobantes2.OptionsPrint.RtfReportHeader = "NOmbre empresa";
        GridViewComprobantes2.OptionsPrint.RtfPageHeader = LblTitulo.Text;
        GridViewComprobantes2.OptionsPrint.AutoWidth = true;

        GridViewComprobantes2.ShowRibbonPrintPreview();
```